# Backbone routes are not working

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am creating a simple `Backbone` app and the routing is not working.  Here is my router.

```
define(function(require) {
  'use strict';

  var Backbone = require('backbone');
  var Header = require('views/header.view');
  var MainBody = require('views/main.body.view');

  var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
      "": "main",
      "about/": "about"
    },

    main: function() {
      var header = new Header();
      $('#header').html(header.render());

      var body = new MainBody();
      $('#app').html(body.render());
    },

    about: function() {
      console.log("About");
    }
  });

  return Router;
});
```

I hit the `/` route as expected, but when I go to `/about`, it never hits the `about` function.  Am I supposed to have a hash in the url somewhere?  What else could I be missing that would cause this issue?

Comment: Have you tried going to #about ?

Comment: That worked.  Make an answer out of it so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because routes are explicitly matched, so `"about/": "about"` will match `/about/` and `"about": "about"` will match `/about`

There is a way to match both `/about` and `/about/` and it requires using optional matchers `(matcher)` so your routes hash key will look like this

```
"about(/)": "about"
```

For hashless routes to work you need to run `Backbone.history.start({pushState: true})`.

Comment: I tried `about` and `about(/)` and both didn't work.  There error I get is `Cannot GET /app/about`.

Comment: If `#about` worked then you ran `Backbone.history.start()`. For `/about` to work you need to run `Backbone.history.start({pushState: true})` (it wont work on IE8 and lower).

Answer (score 0):

According to backbonejs documentation, routers should be defined and addressed as follows:

```
var Workspace = Backbone.Router.extend({

  routes: {
    "help":                 "help",    // #help
    "search/:query":        "search",  // #search/kiwis
    "search/:query/p:page": "search"   // #search/kiwis/p7
  },

  help: function() {
    ...
  },

  search: function(query, page) {
    ...
  }

});
```

Therefore, when you type `http://<URL>/backbonepage#help`, the help function will be invoked